# data.table join (Error in vecseq) is key necessary on both on X and i?

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am new to R and to `data.table`, which I find useful and fast. I am trying to join 2 data tables:

```
> TotFreq
        Legacy_Store_Number WeekDay       Date     Item_Key        Distr NoSellingDays meanUnits ItemType
     1:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000120 2.428985e-04             0      8.00       FM
     2:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000126 1.104030e-03             0     47.50       FM
     3:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000170 1.126004e-03             0     48.75       FM
     4:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000180 5.143034e-04             0     19.00       FM
     5:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000260 3.854306e-04             0     12.25       FM
160167:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978125002327 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM
160168:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978141970584 1.770796e-06            25      1.00       SM
160169:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978145300697 1.180531e-06            26      1.00       SM
160170:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978145552558 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM
160171:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978160139536 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM

> Count_SM_FM
    Legacy_Store_Number WeekDay ItemType ObjItems
 1:              113802       1       SM    12305
 2:              113802       1       FM     1942
 3:              113802       2       SM    11014
 4:              113802       2       FM     1398
 5:              113802       3       SM    10154
 6:              113802       3       FM     1117
 7:              113802       4       SM    10414
 8:              113802       4       FM     1167
 9:              113802       5       SM    10258
10:              113802       5       FM     1200
11:              113802       6       SM    11116
12:              113802       6       FM     1575
13:              113802       7       SM    13098
14:              113802       7       FM     2326
> setkey(TotFreq,Legacy_Store_Number,WeekDay,ItemType)
> 
> ResultJoin <- TotFreq[Count_SM_FM]
Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 320342 rows; more than 160171 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
```

But I do not have duplicate keys in `i`!

Using:

```
> ResultJoin <- TotFreq[Count_SM_FM,allow.cartesian=T]
> 
> ResultJoin
        Legacy_Store_Number WeekDay       Date     Item_Key        Distr NoSellingDays meanUnits ItemType ItemType.1 ObjItems
     1:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000120 2.428985e-04             0      8.00       FM         SM    12305
     2:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000126 1.104030e-03             0     47.50       FM         SM    12305
     3:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000170 1.126004e-03             0     48.75       FM         SM    12305
     4:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000180 5.143034e-04             0     19.00       FM         SM    12305
     5:              113802       1 2013-03-24 000000000260 3.854306e-04             0     12.25       FM         SM    12305
    ---                                                                                                                      
320338:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978125002327 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM         FM     2326
320339:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978141970584 1.770796e-06            25      1.00       SM         FM     2326
320340:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978145300697 1.180531e-06            26      1.00       SM         FM     2326
320341:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978145552558 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM         FM     2326
320342:              113802       7 2013-03-23 978160139536 5.902655e-07            27      1.00       SM         FM     2326
```

I get in fact double the records  that I had in my original `TotFreq` table. If I add a key also on `Count_SM_FM` the join works:

```
> setkey(TotFreq,Legacy_Store_Number,WeekDay,ItemType)
> setkey(Count_SM_FM,Legacy_Store_Number,WeekDay,ItemType)
> ResultJoin <- TotFreq[Count_SM_FM]
> 
> ResultJoin
        Legacy_Store_Number WeekDay ItemType       Date     Item_Key        Distr NoSellingDays meanUnits ObjItems
     1:              113802       1       FM 2013-03-24 000000000120 2.428985e-04             0      8.00     1942
     2:              113802       1       FM 2013-03-24 000000000126 1.104030e-03             0     47.50     1942
     3:              113802       1       FM 2013-03-24 000000000170 1.126004e-03             0     48.75     1942
     4:              113802       1       FM 2013-03-24 000000000180 5.143034e-04             0     19.00     1942
     5:              113802       1       FM 2013-03-24 000000000260 3.854306e-04             0     12.25     1942
    ---                                                                                                           
160167:              113802       7       SM 2013-03-23 978125002327 5.902655e-07            27      1.00    13098
160168:              113802       7       SM 2013-03-23 978141970584 1.770796e-06            25      1.00    13098
160169:              113802       7       SM 2013-03-23 978145300697 1.180531e-06            26      1.00    13098
160170:              113802       7       SM 2013-03-23 978145552558 5.902655e-07            27      1.00    13098
160171:              113802       7       SM 2013-03-23 978160139536 5.902655e-07            27      1.00    13098
```

I tried to verify with an example, maybe the problem was in not having the key variables as the first columns in `TotFreq` or in not having `Count_SM_FM` not sorted but I couldn't reproduce the error

```
> daysType <- data.table(
+     key1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
+     key2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6,7,7),
+     key3=c("b","a","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b","a","b"),
+     var1=c(2,4,6,8,4,5,7,3,7,9,6,3,5,6)
+ )        
> 
> 
> detailData <- data.table(
+     key1=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1),
+     key2=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,6,6,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7,7,7,7,7),
+     var2=c(10,11,12,13,15,16,17,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,10,11,12,15,16,17,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,10,11,13,14,15,16,17,10,11,12,13,14,15,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17),
+     var3=c(1,2,4,6,6,7,3,6,8,9,3,5,7,8,6,7,8,6,7,2,4,6,7,8,2,3,5,7,4,7,8,3,6,4,2,5,7,3,6,7,3,4,2,4,6,4,7,2,9),
+     key3=c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b")
+ )        
> 
> setkey(detailData,key1,key2,key3)
> JoinResult <- detailData[daysType]
```

The problem is different than that in question

> Join of two data.tables fails

because there the `allow.cartesian` solves the issue.

What is the problem here? Why adding the key to `Count_SM_FM` solves it?

Thanks!

Comment: @Arun: I do have duplicate values in `X` (but not in `i`) and I want the values of variable `ObjItems` in `i` on all the duplicates. When I use `allow.cartesian.true` I get double the records, while if I also set the key on `i` I obtain the original number of records and exactly what I want.

Answer (score 4):

**Update Oct 2014:** Arun fixed it in v1.9.5 :

> `allow.cartesian` is now ignored when `i` has no duplicates, [#742](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/742) and [#508](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/508). Thanks to @nigmastar, @user3645882 and others for the reports.

---

---

Previous answer ...

First let's address the `allow.cartesian` part. The error message should probably be changed to point out that you can get large sizes even if you don't have duplicates in `i`, but you have duplicates in the left hand side `data.table`. Here's a simple example:

```
dt1 = data.table(a = c(1,1), b = 1:2, key = 'a')
dt2 = data.table(a = c(1,2), c = 3:4)

dt1[dt2] # this gives an error, because join results in 3 rows, as seen below

dt1[dt2, allow.cartesian = TRUE]
#   a  b c
#1: 1  1 3
#2: 1  2 3
#3: 2 NA 4
```

Now as far as setting the key goes - no you don't need to set the key for `i`, it will just assume the first few columns are the keys. Looking at your first join result one can see that it was **not** joined on `ItemType` and that you're using an older `data.table` version (I'm using 1.9.3). So my guess is that either you didn't actually set the key correctly and didn't include `ItemType` or there was some bug in older versions that's been fixed since then.

Comment: Thank you! I am in fact using v 1.9.2 which is the last one in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/index.html. And I did include ItemType in my key, you can see it just before the join in the firt code snippet.

Comment: I'm also getting this error message if `i` has keys which are not in the LHS table and which is fixed by `nomatch = 0`. Don't know if this is the solution to the problem, but in this case the error message is also miss leading (version 1.9.2).

Comment: @Beasterfield, I think you're right that it's a bit misleading that it says `i` has duplicate keys, when the condition is `max(nrow(x), nrow(i))` could also happen for the case eddi has shown as well. Filed a [DR #5712](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=5712&group_id=240&atid=5356).