# r data.table ( <= 1.9.4) join behaviour

Tags: r, join, data.table

I am back to using r and data.table after some time and I still have issue with the join. I previously asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23809517/data-table-join-error-in-vecseq-is-key-necessary-on-both-on-x-and-i) resulting in a satisfactory explanation but I still do not really get the logic.
Let's consider a few examples:

```
library("data.table")
X <- data.table(chiave=c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),valore1=1:5)
Y <- data.table(chiave=c("a", "b", "c", "d"),valore2=1:4)
X
   chiave valore1
1:      a       1
2:      a       2
3:      a       3
4:      b       4
5:      b       5
 Y
   chiave valore2
1:      a       1
2:      b       2
3:      c       3
4:      d       4
```

when I join I get the error:

```
 setkey(X,chiave)
 X[Y]
# Error in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin) NULL else as.integer(max(nrow(x),  : 
  Join results in 7 rows; more than 5 = max(nrow(x),nrow(i)). Check for duplicate key values in i, each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try including `j` and dropping `by` (by-without-by) so that j runs for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
```

so:

```
 X[Y,allow.cartesian=T]
   chiave valore1 valore2
1:      a       1       1
2:      a       2       1
3:      a       3       1
4:      b       4       2
5:      b       5       2
6:      c      NA       3
7:      d      NA       4
```

Please note that `X` has duplicate keys and `i` doesn't. If I change `Y` to:

```
 Y <- data.table(chiave=c("b", "c", "d"),valore2=1:3)
 Y
   chiave valore2
1:      b       1
2:      c       2
3:      d       3
```

The join is done with no error message and no need for the allow.cartesian, but logically the situation is the same: `X` has multiple keys and `i` doesn't.

```
 X[Y]
   chiave valore1 valore2
1:      b       4       1
2:      b       5       1
3:      c      NA       2
4:      d      NA       3
```

On the other hand:

```
 X <- data.table(chiave=c("a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"),valore1=1:8)
 Y <- data.table(chiave=c("b", "b", "d"),valore2=1:3)
 X
   chiave valore1
1:      a       1
2:      a       2
3:      a       3
4:      a       4
5:      a       5
6:      a       6
7:      b       7
8:      b       8
 Y
   chiave valore2
1:      b       1
2:      b       2
3:      d       3
```

I have multiple keys in both `X` and `i` but the join (and a cartesian product) is done, with no error message and no need for `allow.cartesian`

```
 setkey(X,chiave)
 X[Y]
   chiave valore1 valore2
1:      b       7       1
2:      b       8       1
3:      b       7       2
4:      b       8       2
5:      d      NA       3
```

From my point of view, I need to be warned if and only if I have multiple keys in both X and i (not just if the resulting table has more rows than `max(nrow(x),nrow(i)`)) and only in this case I see the need of `allow.cartesian` (so not in my first two examples).

Comment: Which version of `data.table` are you using? It seems to work with 1.9.5.

Comment: I am using 1.9.4. It's not that it doesn't work, it's that I find strange the way it behaves. Do my examples get different error messages in v. 1.9.5?

Comment: No error message with `setkey(X,chiave); X[Y]`.

Comment: Absolutely right. Fixed in `v1.9.5`. Check [point 9 under bug fixes](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md). PS: please remove the `>` from your post for easy copy/paste.

Comment: @Arun Where can I find v.1.9.5 in [mirror](http://cran.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CRAN/) I can see v 1.9.4

Comment: It's the current [devel version](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation). CRAN version (v1.9.6) will follow anytime soon.. Odd versions are devel, even on CRAN. Have a look at the project homepage I've linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to keep this answered, this behaviour with `allow.cartesian` has been fixed in the current development version `v1.9.5`, and will be soon available on CRAN as `v1.9.6`. Odd versions are devel, and even stable. From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 9. `allow.cartesian` is ignored during joins when:
>
>    - `i` has no duplicates and `mult="all"`. Closes [#742](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/742). Thanks to @nigmastar for the report.
>    - assigning by reference, i.e., `j` has `:=`. Closes [#800](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/800). Thanks to @matthieugomez for the report.
>
>    In both these cases (and during a `not-join` which was already fixed in [1.9.4](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md#bug-fixes-1)), `allow.cartesian` can be safely ignored.